# Expand div on hover

Tags: html, hover, expand

i tried doing it with css, the closest i got was: http://jsfiddle.net/XyDec/
It kind of works, but don't hide the content inside it and i would like some smooth animation
, so i guess it's scripts time.
i can't write them or don't know where to look for them, could anybody help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may take a look at the jquery javascript framework (user friendly and powerfull)
here is an example of smooth slide down of div using jquery:

http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

this is made with one line : `$("div").slideDown("slow");`

hope it help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried jQuery? You can treat the div as an object and assign an action to an event, through jQuery methods.

For instance:

```
function hide(){
$('#the-div').hide('slow')
}
```

Then you just call the function on the hover event.

If you want to go a step further, you can assign a timer for it to show again. Or even use a callback.

```
function hide(){
var x = $('#the-div')
$('#the-div').hide('slow', function(x){
    //do something with the variable x
    })
}
```

I think that should work.

Hope that helps.

Cheers.